# Mirrored geometry does not receive the same material?

Tags: materials, node-editor

Node editor is just as below:
[image]
I mirror the eye with an empty.
How do I get the same mirrored object?

Comment: maybe you should use the 'generated' option for using with the mapping node. Or place the object 'eyes' origin where you put your empty, remove the later one.

Comment: Is anyone using this file? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/484/, or should I delete it? It links to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion

Apply the mirror, separate the eyes, transform origin to geometry, uv map, and apply a circular texture.

I do not think attempting to apply the same texture space of [Object] to both eyes in an easy or flexible idea.  If the eyes rotate you may find trouble.  I do not know your animation style.

---

Secondary Information , Not a suggestion

Here is deprecated texture mapping without uv with typical sticky style ... it is biased to the vector indicated

[image]

If you choose to have bad frozen eyes with a slippery texture this is a bad deprecated node image.

[image]

Both images above rely on the spherical shape and have no uv map required.

Comment: Also the anwser! Thanks. Thought Mirror Mod would create another eye as a seperate object haha